# DOM object only requires two clicks in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, prototypejs, dom-events

I'm really struggling with the following bit of code.  I'm still really new to using DOM with Javascript and this script is running flawlessly in FireFox, Chrome and Safari.  In Internet Explorer it requires two clicks.  If you visit the link in FireFox and then the same link in Internet Explorer you'll see that if you click a shape in FireFox it immediately shows the colour options if you do this in Internet Explorer it will not show the colour options until you've clicked on the shape twice or on a shape and then another shape.  Can an IE, DOM, Javascript Ninja tell me what's wrong with the script that cause the need for two clicks in IE?

```
<?php 
$swatches = $this->get_option_swatches();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
        try {
            var swatches = <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($swatches); ?>;

            function find_swatch(key, value) {
                for (var i in swatches) {
                    if (swatches[i].key == key && swatches[i].value == value)
                        return swatches[i];
                }
                return null;
            }

            function has_swatch_key(key) {
                for (var i in swatches) {
                    if (swatches[i].key == key)
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            function create_swatches(label, select) {
                // create swatches div, and append below the <select>
                var sw = new Element('div', {'class': 'swatches-container'});
                select.up().appendChild(sw);

                // store these element to use later for recreate swatches
                select.swatchLabel = label;
                select.swatchElement = sw;

                // hide select
                select.setStyle({position: 'absolute', top: '-9999px'});

                $A(select.options).each(function(opt, i) {
                    if (opt.getAttribute('value')) {
                        var elm;
                        var key = trim(opt.innerHTML);

                        // remove price
                        if (opt.getAttribute('price')) key = trim(key.replace(/\+([^+]+)$/, ''));

                        var item = find_swatch(label, key);
                        if (item)
                            elm = new Element('img', {
                                src: '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA); ?>swatches/'+item.img, 
                                alt: opt.innerHTML, 
                                title: opt.innerHTML, 
                                'class': 'swatch-img'});
                        else {
                            console.debug(label, key, swatches);
                            elm = new Element('a', {'class': 'swatch-span'});
                            elm.update(opt.innerHTML);
                        }
                        elm.observe('click', function(event) {
                            select.selectedIndex = i;
                            fireEvent(select, 'change');
                            var cur = sw.down('.current');
                            if (cur) cur.removeClassName('current');
                            elm.addClassName('current');
                        });
                        sw.appendChild(elm);
                    }
                });

            }
            // Hide Second Option's Label
            function hideStuff(id) {
                if (document.getElementById(id)) {
                    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
            hideStuff("last-option-label");
            function showStuff(id) {
                if (document.getElementById(id)) {
                    document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';
                }
            }

            function recreate_swatches_recursive(select) {
                // remove the old swatches
                if (select.swatchElement) {
                    select.up().removeChild(select.swatchElement);
                    select.swatchElement = null;
                }

                // create again
                if (!select.disabled)
                    showStuff("last-option-label");
                    create_swatches(select.swatchLabel, select);

                // recursively recreate swatches for the next select
                if (select.nextSetting)
                    recreate_swatches_recursive(select.nextSetting);
            }

            function fireEvent(element,event){
                if (document.createEventObject){
                    // dispatch for IE
                    var evt = document.createEventObject();
                    return element.fireEvent('on'+event, evt);      
                }
                else{
                    // dispatch for firefox + others
                    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
                    evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
                    return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
                }
            }

            function trim(str) {
                return str.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
            }


            $$('#product-options-wrapper dt').each(function(dt) {

                // get custom option's label
                var label = '';
                $A(dt.down('label').childNodes).each(function(node) {
                    if (node.nodeType == 3) label += node.nodeValue;
                });
                label = trim(label);

                var dd = dt.next();
                var select = dd.down('select');
                if (select && has_swatch_key(label)) {
                    create_swatches(label, select);

                    // if configurable products, recreate swatches of the next select when the current select change
                    if (select.hasClassName('super-attribute-select')) {
                        select.observe('change', function() {
                            recreate_swatches_recursive(select.nextSetting);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch(e) {
            alert("Color Swatches javascript error. Please report this error to support@galathemes.com. Error:" + e.message);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you try to cut down the code example to just the part that is relevant to your problem?

Comment: Hi Ben there's no error being produced and I'm not quite sure where the problem lies...  That's why I've dropped in the entire script.  Like I said it works fine in FF, Chrome & Safari it's only in IE the strange behaviour occurs.

Comment: I've found strange part on your code $$('#product-options-wrapper dt') Why did you use double $ for that?

Comment: Hi InspiredJW it's not my code but I've been staring at it long enough it's starting to feel like it is...  I believe that the double $ are there because of the prototype.js used.

_Because of browsers that don't support this you must take care to use DOM extensions only on elements that have been extended. For instance, the example above works in FF and Opera, but add Element.extend(my_div) after creating the element to make the script really solid. You can use the dollar function as a shortcut like in the following example:_

Comment: `// this will error out in IE: 
$('someElement').parentNode.hide()
// to make it cross-browser:
$($('someElement').parentNode).hide()`

This is referenced here [How Prototype Extends DOM](http://prototypejs.org/learn/extensions)

Comment: In any case if one of the $$ are removed it breaks the code in all browsers...

Comment: Hi @TravelingAdMan It seems you are using http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/gala-color-swatches-free-9787.html

Is it still working for you. for me it works for me in FF and Chrome with a js error.  
TypeError: select.up is not a function
select.up().appendChild(sw);

Can you help me if you have ever got it worknig properly.

Answer (score 0):

console.debug has been deprecated. In the "function create_swatches(label, select)" where it is written **"console.debug(label, key, swatches);"** change it to **"console.log(label, key, swatches);"** or **you can just delete that line of code all together**....... thaterrorbegone